# Flurry CSV Download (API) Event Count Mismatch

Tags: flurry

I was testing a CSV download of my app events using the API.
I noticed that the CSV had different event counts for different calls for the same time period.
All data (for each download) was correct for my app and the requested time periods. 
Does anyone knows if they sample the data to create the file for download?

Edited to include sample call, code for extraction, and result for 2 calls for the same time period.

Call

```
str_init = '20191101'
str_end = '20191102'

# Call data extraction for Flurry from IOS app
get_csv_from_flurry(str_init, str_end, 'IOS')
```

Code for Extraction

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import requests
import json
import time

from functions.ribon_path import ribon_root_path_join
from functions.ribon_s3_integration import ribon_upload_to_s3

"""
Make CSV extraction from flurry based on initial date (yyyy-mm-dd), end date (yyyy-mm-dd) and platform
Save Uncompressed CSV locally for processing
Save compressed file (parquet) to S3 for backup
"""
def get_csv_from_flurry(str_ini, str_end, str_platform):

    # Convert time period to datetime format
    dt_ini = parser.parse(str_ini)
    dt_end = parser.parse(str_end)

    def unix_time_millis(dt):
        # Convert date periods to unix milisecon epoch
        epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
        return (dt - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0

    epoch_ini = unix_time_millis(dt_ini)
    epoch_end = unix_time_millis(dt_end)

    #print(epoch_ini)
    #print(epoch_fim)

    if str_platform == 'IOS' :
        Flurry_apiKey = 'XXX' 
    else :
        Flurry_apiKey = 'YYY'

    # Build the parameters of the post request to the flurry API
    url = 'https://rawdata.flurry.com/pulse/v1/rawData'
    payload = {"data": {
                "type":"rawData",
                "attributes":{
                       "startTime": epoch_ini,
                       "endTime": epoch_end,
                       "outputFormat": "CSV",
                       "apiKey": Flurry_apiKey
                       }
                            }
               }
    headers = {"accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
               "authorization": "Bearer ZZZ",
               "cache-control": "no-cache",
               "content-type": "application/vnd.api+json"
               }
    #print(payload)
    # Make the request
    print('Make Request to Flurry')
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    #print(r.content)

    # Test the return, get the status, download url and request id
    test = r.json()
    #print(teste['data']['attributes']['s3URI'])
    #print(teste['data']['id'])
    r_s3URI = test['data']['attributes']['s3URI']
    r_id = test['data']['id']

    # Check if the download link is ready
    url = 'https://rawdata.flurry.com/pulse/v1/rawData/' + r_id + '?fields[rawData]=requestStatus,s3URI'
    #print(url)
    payload = {}
    headers = {"accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
               "authorization": "Bearer ZZZ",
               "cache-control": "no-cache",
               "content-type": "application/vnd.api+json"
               }
    print('Request OK')

    # Check each minute if the download link is ready
    print('Start Pooling to Check if the File is Ready for Download')
    while r_s3URI == None:
        time.sleep(60) 
        # Make the request
        r = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        print(r.content)
        test = r.json()
        #print(test['data']['attributes']['s3URI'])
        r_s3URI = test['data']['attributes']['s3URI']

    # When the download is ready, get the file and save 
    # Set local folder to save file
    flurry_filename = str_ini + '_' + str_end + '_' + str_platform + '.csv.gz'
    flurry_path_gz = ribon_root_path_join('data', 'Flurry_Download', flurry_filename)

    # Download the file
    print('Start Flurry Download')
    myfile = requests.get(r_s3URI)
    open(flurry_path_gz, 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

[On the link there is an image with the 2 files I got, they are not the same size and don't have the same number of records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKVH8.png)

Comment: Data is not sampled to create the API downloads. Can you post a clip of the data that shows the discrepancy, as well as the API call?

Comment: I edited the question with the information that was requested. If you need some more info to help me debug let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from Flurry Support, I found out the differences.
For API downloads older than 15 days, the API calls are giving the same numbers every time.
API calls for dates up to 15 days most times get different results (newer calls with more records). The older the call the smaller the difference, so I agree with the support that this can be accounted for late arriving events.
Flurry is not online and works by queuing data on the mobile and dumping that to the server.